# mod_ldap and mod_authnz_ldap not building for Apache httpd 2.4.4 and SVN

Tags: apache

**Problem**: I am trying to compile the Apache web server using the latest sources of httpd, apr and apr-util, and enabling LDAP support.  My current steps do not seem to be commpiling mod_ldap.so and mod_authnz_ldap.so.

**Environment background**:  Build and target OS are RHEL5.  A non-LDAP enabled instance of httpd is already on the server (2.4.1) and SVN 1.7.3 is already installed and works anonymously with httpd-2.4.1

**Steps to reproduce**:
Following the compilation instructions [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html) I have downloaded:

- httpd-2.4.4 in /path/apache/src/httpd-2.4.4
- apr 1.4.6 in /path/apache/src/apr-1.4.6
- apr-utils 1.5.2 /path/apache/src/apr-util-1.5.2
- OpenLDAP and Berkley DB (for the LDAP libraries to build apr-util against) in /path/openldap-2.4.35_src and /path/db-5.3.21_src

With the sources in place, I:
compiled BDB and installed it to /path/db-5.3.21
compiled OpenLDAP using the installed BDB and installed it in /path/openldap-2.4.35
configured apr, compiled and installed it in /path/apache/apr
configured apr-util with:

`./configure --with-ldap --prefix=/path/apache/apr-util-1.5.2 --with-apr=/path/apache/apr-1.4.6 --with-ldap-lib=/path/openldap-2.4.35/lib --with-ldap-include=/path/openldap-2.4.35/include`

Afterwards, I built and installed with `make` and `make install`.

Finally, I configured httpd with the following:

```
   ./configure --prefix=/path/apache/httpd-2.4.4 --with-apr=/path/apache/apr-1.4.6 --with-apr-util=/path/apache/apr-util-1.5.2 --with-pcre=/path/apache/pcre-8.30 --with-ldap --enable-ldap
```

This was successful, and I was able to run `make` and `make install`

I now have a httpd instance in /path/apache/httpd-2.4.4/.  Using /path/httpd-2.4.1/httpd.conf as a model, I matched the existing configuration and loaded modules, adding:

`LoadModule mod_ldap modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule mod_authnz_ldap modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so`

However, if I run apachectl start I get a syntax error:

`/path/apache/httpd-2.4.4> ./bin/apachectl start
httpd: Syntax error on line 148 of /path/apache/httpd-2.4.4/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure 'mod_ldap' in file /path/apache/httpd-2.4.4/modules/mod_ldap.so: /path/apache/httpd-2.4.4/modules/mod_ldap.so: undefined symbol: mod_ldap`

Looking within the httpd-2.4.4/modules directory, the modules mod_ldap.so and mod_authnz.ldap.so are missing.  I have tried the above steps without success.  I have discovered that within the src/httpd-2.4.4 directory, the files ./modules/aaa/.libs/mod_authnz_ldap.so and ./modules/ldap/.libs/mod_ldap.so exist, but copying those over to httpd-2.4.4/modules does not alleviate the issue.

Can someone assist me in diagnosing the error in my steps?  I know I'm missing something, but I have been unable to find it so far.  I will also add any other required information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

As configured above, LDAP is supported through a shared module.  To enable the modules defined (including LDAP in my case) you need to configure apache with the --enable-so flag.  This will generate the shared modules and place them within the modules directory when compiled/installed.

Additional reference can be found in this SO article:  [Compiling Apache Web Server with Dynamic Module Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259820/compiling-apache-web-server-with-dynamic-module-support)